# Return both Variables in JSON

Tags: node.js, rest, resize

How do i return both variables as json so i can be able to read it from Postman and use in my application? I have something that i am trying to get, like get a Base64string and then resize it and return the resized strings both

My code is looking like this

```
app.post('/api/resizebase64', (req, res) =>{
    var base64str = req.body.base64tr;

    var frontendLogo = resizebase64(base64str, 112, 34);
    var emailLogo = resizebase64(base64str, 165, 50);

    if(error) throw error;
     //return the both variables as Json
});
```

How do I go about this?
Kindly point me in right direction

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.post('/api/resizebase64', (req, res) => {
  var base64str = req.body.base64tr;

  var frontendLogo = resizebase64(base64str, 112, 34);
  var emailLogo = resizebase64(base64str, 165, 50);

  if (error) throw error;
  //return the both variables as Json

  res.json({
    frontendLogo,
    emailLogo
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but it gives an Error, says document  document is not defined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at module.exports

Comment: If you dont have any other error   res.json({
    frontendLogo,
    emailLogo
  }) should fix your problem.